Propagate/continue the traces from a client sending traces via custom headers in Springboot 3.4
We have a Springboot 3.4 web service with micrometer, serving traffic for two clients.
Client one, we are lucky, is also using Springboot 3+. Like magic, Springboot is able to "propagate", "continue" the trace from client one.
We are able to see something like this:

However, there is also a client two. They add tracing information inside their custom header.
In our server app, we are able to see the customs headers
headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.printf("Header '%s' = %s%n", key, value);
        });

2024-12-10T00:00 [innertrace,,]  INFO 8110 --- [innertrace] [nio-8081-exec-2] [490bdd15c3a1337b6477c965883d1ced-34af6c6a1075a0c6] com.example.innertrace.HelloController   : How many header? 10
Header 'ot-custom-traceid' = 8f7ebd8a73f9a8f50e6a00a87a20952a
Header 'ot-custom-spanid' = 1b08f18b8858bb9a
Header 'content-type' = application/json

However, maybe because the traces come from a custom header, we are not able to "propagate" or "continue" the traces.
Issues:

In this example, the client one is sending us 8f7ebd8a73f9a8f50e6a00a87a20952a 1b08f18b8858bb9a but we are not able to get those.
Our app would create new traces in the log 490bdd15c3a1337b6477c965883d1ced 34af6c6a1075a0c6
we are not able to see the client trace in observability systems, but only the new wrong traces.


While we have end-to-end client one -> server trace information, we are losing information for client two. For client two, we are only seeing the server side of information.
Since we are using Springboot 3.4+, we would like to avoid having to add dependencies on old Spring Cloud Seuth if possible.
Question, how to continue or propagate the traces sent from custom headers sent by a client?

Your explanation is good but without doing some wireshark and seeing all the code is difficult to debug
